# Can't send request in soapclient and https

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

My routine works fine under http protocol, but recently i needed to upgrade to https and is no longer working. I have no idea what is going on and i tried a lot of different codes on the web.

The error message is Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host [...]

I'm using php v.5.6 but it would be preferable if this solution works also in 5.3.37.

Here is my code, thanks for helping

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 1000);


$url_wsdl ="https://exampleservice.cls?WSDL=1&CacheUserName=myusername&CachePassword=mypassword&CacheNoRedirect=1";


print 'Starting routine';
//logging in
$curl = curl_init($url_wsdl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);


// get cookies
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
curl_close($curl);
print 'Curl....ok. Cookies ok<br>';


$options = array(
    'trace'             => 1
    , 'cache_wsdl'      => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    , 'user_agent'      => 'PHP WS'
    , 'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3

);

$soapClient = new SoapClient($url_wsdl,$options  );
print 'SoapClient....ok<br>';

//sending cookies to soapclient
foreach ($cookies as $name => $value) {
    print '------> sending cookies: '. $value . '<br>';
    $soapClient->__setCookie($name, $value);
}
print 'SetCookies....ok<br>';


$data = array('TesteInterface' => array('Request' => array('Mensagem' => 'teste')));
$response = $soapClient->__soapCall("TesteInterface",$data);
print 'SoapCall....ok<br>';

print 'Response:<br>';
print_r($response);


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out by setting endpoint manually. It was pointing to a no https adress. Now it works

```
$soapClient->__setLocation('https://myservice.cls');
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if your server has the `openssl` library, then check for the openssl php extension to be activated.

After that you can improve your wsdl `$options`:

```
$options = [
            'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            'connection_timeout' => 60, //or other
            'keep_alive' => false,
            'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS, //or other
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
                'ssl' => [
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true,
                ],
            ]),
        ];
```

Comment: openssl is enabled in phpinfo().  i've improved the options section with your code, but still not working

Comment: what about the openssl on the server?  what version do you have?

Comment: openssl v 1.0.2k-fips

Comment: try to add also a `crypto_method` under the `stream_context => 'ssl'` if you have any (chiphers too). And try to use a `try-catch` and print the error you get

Comment: using  'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_CLIENT, but still not working. Error message is the same with try-catch

Comment: go on the server and try to manually `curl` or (`wget`) to see if you have access to the `wsdl` URL.  (And you may want to add `ciphers` to `ssl` option too)